# Get specific entry in case of duplicate entry

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

**Situation:**
I have a scenario in which I get data with all the fields same except just one field. I have written a store procedure that gets the data, using many join from different table. In my case I need either of the two case depending on the scenario. 
eg:

**Actual case**

```
  |UserId | First name | Last name | IsRequired | IsDeleted |
     1        harry          tom        true         false
     1        harry          tom        false        false
     3         ram            sham       true         false
```

**Scenario:**

If there are two records on with IsRequired true and false respectively then I need a case with the IsRequired true.

**Problem:**

Now the problem is that I need to filter out the records in the select statement.

So any one has any idea how to do it in a select statement.

**Expected case:**

```
| UserId | First name | Last name | IsRequired | IsDeleted |
    1        harry          tom        true         false
    2        ram            sham       true         false
```

Comment: try Distinct in select query

Comment: Do you need a solution for MySQL, SQL Server or both?

Comment: `select * from table where IsRequired='true'` ?

Comment: I cant use select * from table where IsRequired='true' as it will filter other records with Isrequired true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED SOLUTION:**

```
SELECT UserId, First name, Last name, IsRequired, IsDeleted FROM table WHERE UserId IN (SELECT UserId FROM users GROUP BY UserId HAVING count(distinct(IsRequired)) > 1) and IsRequired = 'true'
UNION
SELECT UserId, First name, Last name, IsRequired, IsDeleted FROM table WHERE UserId IN (SELECT UserId FROM users GROUP BY UserId HAVING count(IsRequired) = 1)
```

Please see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d178f/1/0

Have reproduced the exact same database structure.

Comment: Getting error select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Oh. Are you using SQL Server? I thought you needed a solution for MySQL.

Comment: I've updated the answer. Please check now and tell me if it works or not. I don't have an installed version of SQL Server right now, therefore cannot be sure if it works out of the box.

Comment: its not working the count >0 is returning zero records.

Comment: its working. I have reproduced the same database structure in an sql fiddle. see this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d178f/12

Comment: Please check the updated solution. It's working now.

Comment: Have tested it on both SQL Server 2008 and SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Have updated SQL Fiddle Link in the answer. Please recheck link to see latest fiddle.

Comment: @kanishk please guide me with the solution for:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23737133/get-either-of-the-entry-in-duplicate-records

Comment: Have put an answer. Please check and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Just It is my idea.

Step 1: First of all change your datatype value of IsRequired into `BOOLEAN`. So what you have, In IsRequired column contains the value like `0` or `1`.

step 2: Then using MAX().
Query is

```
SELECT userId,firstname,lastname,MAX(IsRequired),IsDeleted FROM `table_name` GROUP BY userId
```