# Get either of the entry in duplicate records

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

This question is in reference to

> [Get specific entry in case of duplicate entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23650246/get-specific-entry-in-case-of-duplicate-entry)

Now in this scenario the value that is different is `user Id` and the remaining is same.

```
|UserId | First name | Last name | IsRequired | IsDeleted |
     1        harry          tom        true         false
     3        harry          tom        true         false
     3        ram           sham      true         false
```

I need either of the two entry but the scenario mentioned in the link above should also be their..

**Expected Result**

```
| UserId | First name | Last name | IsRequired | IsDeleted |
    1        harry          tom        true         false
    3        ram            sham       true         false
```

User Id can be either `1 or 3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this !

```
create table users(UserId int, Firstname varchar(30), Lastname varchar(30), IsRequired varchar(5), IsDeleted varchar(5));

insert into users values('1','harry','tom','true','false');
insert into users values('1','harry','tom','false','false');
insert into users values('3','ram','sham','true','false');

select * from
(
select *,rn=ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by UserId order by Firstname desc) from users
)x
where x.rn=1
```

### <kbd>[See demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/89cbc/1)</kbd>

Comment: Yes the solution is right in place of first name the IsRequired field if placed works great